# xcode 4.2 can't run app

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2, xcodebuild

**I'm trying to build my app on my iPhone 4 but i keep getting this same error. It has bein run before and has worked fine but i changed my icons and now this is what i get.**

```
   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copypng failed with exit code 1
```

The error is called `CopyPNGFile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have deleted a file in your project's folder without telling XCode, and it still tries to include it. Expand the folders in the Project Navigator and look for files in red, then delete them with a ctrl-click. XCode should be happier after that.